# A curious advice

Tags: discussion, review, review-audit

Dear users I wanted to understand the reason for this warning that appears when I have to check/approve or edit specific questions. What is the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a review audit , to see if your review skills align with the review skills of others.  It also tests a reviewers knowledge of site policy.

Congratulations are not warnings, despite that use in everyday society for things like pregnancy etc.

**Addendum** you can simply click next.